# Reading line using sockets form mx with different charset- iso-8859-2

Tags: java, email, character-encoding

I'm trying to write simple application using sockets in Java to read only headers from mail server reading line by line.
The problem is that sometimes mail subject has different charset ( iso-8859-2 ) and i can not display properly some special characters.What is the proper way to display special characters while using System.out.println("ńł") ?
I know i have to use "String s.get bytes" but either way it does not work. Is there any possibility to display special characters properly. Maybe i'm doing something wrong ( i'm new to java ) but after spending almost a week checking out different codes i'm getting tired.
Here's is the simple code from example testing application ( not original ):

```
String s = "=?ISO-8859-2?Q?Zesp=F3=B3_Gmaila?=";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2"));
String foo = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(foo);
//System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().name());
```

Output:
=?ISO-8859-2?Q?Zesp=F3=B3_Gmaila?=

Example answer from MX:

Subject: =?ISO-8859-2?Q?Gmail_jest_inny=2E_Oto=2C_co_musisz_o_nim_wiedzie=E6=2E?=

Thank you in advance

Adam

I can not past full listning in new comment so here is everything with Esailija help:

```
package javaapplication7;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec;

public class JavaApplication7 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

    String s = "=?ISO-8859-2?Q?Zesp=F3=B3_Gmaila?=";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=\\?([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)\\?Q\\?"); 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if( m.find() ) {
    String encoding = m.group(1);
    String target = s.replaceAll(p.toString(),"");
    QuotedPrintableCodec qpc = new QuotedPrintableCodec(encoding);
    try {
         System.out.println(qpc.decode(target));
         } catch (DecoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
    }
}
```

and error:

```
run:
org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Invalid quoted-printable encoding
    at      org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec.decodeQuotedPrintable(QuotedPrintableCodec.java:189)
at org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec.decode(QuotedPrintableCodec.java:230)
at org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec.decode(QuotedPrintableCodec.java:279)
at org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec.decode(QuotedPrintableCodec.java:300)
at javaapplication7.JavaApplication7.main(JavaApplication7.java:32)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: How are you reading stdout as that will affect what you see

Answer (score 0):

You can see the sourcecode of James Server (is a mail server in Java), you may find answers:

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/james/server/trunk/
- http://james.apache.org/server/

And Mime4J

- http://james.apache.org/mime4j/

Answer (score 0):

Use `QuotedPrintableCodec` from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi):

```
String s = "=?ISO-8859-2?Q?Zesp=F3=B3_Gmaila";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=\\?([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)\\?Q\\?"); //For detecting the encoding
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if( m.find() ) {
    String encoding = m.group(1);
    String target = s.replaceAll( p.toString(), ""); //Remove the encoding header
    QuotedPrintableCodec qpc = new QuotedPrintableCodec(encoding);
    try {
        System.out.println(qpc.decode(target));
        // prints "Zespół_Gmaila"
    } catch (DecoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer guys. I have downloaded org.apache.commons.codec.jar and added it to import but after compilation i get following errors: (import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec; )"org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Invalid quoted-printable encoding at org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec.decodeQuotedPrintable(QuotedPrintableCodec.java:189)".  Any clue's ? Thanks

Comment: I have edited main question 'cause can not past everything in comment. Thanks for help

Comment: @admfotad you need to remove the `=?` from the end

Comment: Thanks a lot- u saved me a lot of time. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have problem with polish characters. I got simple anwser.

```
String s = "=?ISO-8859-2?Q?Zesp=F3=B3_Gmaila?=";
String test=MimeUtility.decodeText(s);

System.out.println(test);
```

The println is ,,Zespół Gmaila''. the library you need is:

```
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
```